# "online" class view window in VS2012 or at least hotkey to open file in Class View

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I like "LocateInSolutionExplorer" Resharper shortcut which allows me to quikly open a file in Solution Explorer. I want to have the same shortcut for "Class View", so I can quickly view public interface of the class. If this is possible?

Ideally while coding and switching between ".cs" files I want to have "online" window which display class hierarchy. Also it should be possible to configure what to show (hide private fields etc.). What can you recommend?

So how to quickly view public interface of the certain (currently opened in text editor) class?

Comment: I know only a click-and-shortcut-solution.
I have always open the File Structure window (Ctrl+Shift+F). If I want to know the class structure I select the class name in File Structure window and type Ctrl+E, Ctrl+H.

Comment: I'm sorry i need "Class view" not class hierarchy. Resharper has shortcuts for displaying hierarchy (subtypes supertypes etc.) But i can find a shortcut to display class structure (class view). I've fixed my question to be more precise.